# Regarding Complex Functional Inverses

Tags: complex-analysis

How does one prove a complex function has an inverse that is also a function.

In addition, does a complex function having an inverse imply there is only one complex input for each complex output.

Sorry for the badly phrased question I am new to complex analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If doesn't matter whether functions are between complex numbers, real numbers, or arbitrary sets $A$ and $B$. Inverse functions may or may not exist. And when inverse functions do exist, there will be only one input for each output, both for the original function and for the inverse. That is a necessary condition for an inverse to exist.

A function $f$ from the set $A$ to the set $B$ (we write this in short-hand as $f: A \to B$) is a rule which assigns to each $a \in A$ exactly one $b \in B$. This notation $f(a)$ is defined to be this unique $b \in B$ assigned to $a$. Any rule, not matter how arbitrary, defines a function as long as it always assigns the same value to $a$.

The *inverse* of $f$, if it exists, is a function $g : B \to A$ which undoes $f$: for all $a \in A, g(f(a)) = a$, and is undone by $f$: for all $b \in B, f(g(b)) = b$. There are two issues that can prevent $g$ from existing:

- While $f$ is required to be defined for every $a \in A$, there is not a similar requirement that every $b \in B$ must be assigned by $f$ to some $a$. For example, if we consider the function $f : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ defined by $f(z) = e^z$, you can see $f(z) \ne 0$ for all $z$. $f$ does not assign $0$ to anything. This prevents $g$ from existing because $f(g(b)) = b$ for all $b$. Thus for any $b \in B$, there has to be a value $g(b) \in A$ to which $b$ is assigned by $f$.
- While $f$ assigns only one $b$ to each $a$, there is no similar requirement that every $b$ is assigned to only one $a$. For example, the function $f : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ defined by $f(z) = z^2$. It is obvious that $f(z) = f(-z)$, so for every $b \in \Bbb C$ except $b = 0$ is assigned to both $\sqrt b$ and to $-\sqrt b$. This prevents an inverse function $g$ from existing because to be a function, $g$ can only assign a value $b \in B$ to a single value in $A$. If $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$, then $g(f(a_1)) = g(f(a_2))$, but $g(f(a_1)) = a_1$ and $g(f(a_2)) = a_2$, so this means $a_1 = a_2$. Thus $g$ can only exist if $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$ only when $a_1 = a_2$.

The first requirement (called surjectivity) has a fairly easy workaround, so it is generally ignored for lower level mathematics. The set $B$ is ours to choose. So we can always choose it to be exactly those elements that are assigned to something by $f$. For example, instead of defining $f(z) = e^z$ as being from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$, I could have defined it as being from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C^* = \{ z \in \Bbb C \mid z \ne 0\}$. (And yes, you can show that every complex number except $0$ can be expressed as $e^z$ for some other complex number $z$.)

The second requirement (called injectivity) has a somewhat harder workaround. Instead of restricting $B$, this time we restrict $A$. For each $b \in B$, we choose exactly one of the values of $a$ to which it is assigned, and kick the all the other such values out of $A$. For example, with the function $f(z) = z^2$, instead of defining it on all of $\Bbb C$, we instead restrict it to $\{z \in \Bbb C \mid \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0 \text{ or } (z = iy \text { with }y > 0)\}$

So, suppose $f : A \to B$ is both surjective (for all $b \in B$, there is some $a \in A$ with $f(a) = b$) and injective (for all $a_1, a_2 \in A$, if $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$, then $a_1 = a_2$). Is that enough to say that an inverse $g$ exists? Well to be a function $g$ just has to follow some definite rule. In this case, we can choose the rule: $g(b) = a$ if and only if $f(a) = b$. Since $f$ is surjective, for every $b in B$, it assigns some value $a \in A$. And since $f$ is injective, for any given $b$, there is only one value $a$ assigned to it. Thus $g$ is a function, and by its rule, $g(f(a)) = a$ and $f(g(b)) = b$ for all $a$ and $b$, so it is the inverse of $f$. So a function has an inverse if and only if it is surjective and injective.

Of the two examples, $f : \{z \in \Bbb C \mid \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0 \text{ or } (z = iy \text { with }y > 0)\} \to \Bbb C$ defined by $f(z) = z^2$ has an inverse $g : \Bbb C \to \{z \in \Bbb C \mid \operatorname{Re}(z) > 0 \text{ or } (z = iy \text { with }y > 0)\} \to \Bbb C$.

The other function $f : \Bbb C \to \Bbb C^*$ defined by $f(z) = e^z$ still fails to have an inverse even though the restriction to $\Bbb C^*$ makes it surjective. The problem is that unlike it's restriction to the real numbers, complex exponentiation is not injective. In particular, since $e^{2\pi i} = 1$, we have $e^z = e^{z + 2\pi i}$. I'll leave it to you to figure ways to restrict its domain to be injective.